# How can I constrain an image to crop the height with a fix width with CSS?

Tags: html, css

My HTML is:

```
<div class="event-presentation-featured">
  <div class="event-presentation-featued__image-container">
    <a href="...">
      <img class="event-presentation-featued__image" src="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__content">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__actions">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the image to NOT expand the height of the containing div. Presently it looks like:
[image]

The relevant classes are:

```
.event-presentation-featured {
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image-container {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    max-width: 457px;
    position: relative;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Its hard to understand your problem here. Why can you not just set the height of `.event-presentation-featured__image` to not be 100%. if you make it a px value then it will set the image to be that height exactly regardless of div

Comment: The `px` value will be determined by how much text is in the `2023 Quad Annual Report`

Comment: The image is already 100% height

Comment: so your looking for the height of the image and the height of the text to be equal? are you able to ammend the question with a picture of what you want it to look like as well as an example of what it currently looks like so i can see the difference?

Comment: Please add an [mcve].

Comment: "*The px value will be determined by how much text is in the 2023 Quad Annual Report*" What do you mean? The 2023 Quad Annual Report in your image is a title, and a link to download a file. Do you mean you plan to generate and fill all the text from the report into the DOM?

Comment: Your request makes no sense. If your report is 100,000 words long do you want the image as tall as the whole webpage?

Comment: Doesn't it work to simply put the image in absolute ?

Comment: Hi @Shamoon, as per my understanding about your query, you want a fixed width container for image which should not change height of container. 
I can suggest you to try CSS clip-path property for image cropping. https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ 
I hope this will be helpful. Thanks. Jignesh R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set a fixed height on the image container, and then use `object-fit` and `object-position` properties on the image itself.

Here is how the Below CSS Code will work:

I have set a fixed height on the `.event-presentation-featued__image-container.` You can adjust this height to your desired value.

I used `overflow: hidden` on the container to hide any content that may exceed the fixed height.

I have set the width of `.event-presentation-featued__image` to `100%` to ensure it stretches to the width of its container.

`object-fit: cover` is used to make the image cover the entire container while maintaining its aspect ratio, effectively cropping it to fit the fixed height.

Then, `object-position: center` centers the cropped area of the image both horizontally and vertically.

```
.event-presentation-featued__image-container {
    max-width: 457px; /* Optional: Set a maximum width for the container */
    height: 200px; /* Set a fixed height for the image container */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide any overflowing content */
    position: relative;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* Set the height to 100% to cover the fixed container height */
    object-fit: cover; /* Crop the image to cover the container while maintaining the aspect ratio */
    object-position: center; /* Center the cropped area of the image */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste `<img>` to wrapper, and add `position: absolute;` with `object-fit: cover;`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.card{
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  /* you can also add min-height to card */
  /* min-height: 200px; */
}

.card-img {
  flex: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-img img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-body{
  display: grid;
  gap: 12px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
    <div class="card-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, quod, sit, vero iusto blanditiis rem similique dicta nihil consectetur culpa saepe voluptates quo cum incidunt quis dolorum quisquam beatae eum odit dolor officiis voluptatum quam autem nisi ratione doloribus laborum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for the image to fill the available space but NOT to expand the container. In which case something like this might work for you without modifying the existing html.

```css
.event-presentation-featured {
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.event-presentation-featured__content {
  background: #eee;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.event-presentation-featured__actions {
  background: #eeddcc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image-container {
  flex-basis: 250px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image-container a {
  position: relative;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-presentation-featured">
  <div class="event-presentation-featued__image-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="event-presentation-featued__image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__content">
    <p>August 3, 2022</p>
    <h1>2023 Quad Annual Report</h1>
    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__actions">
    <button>Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/><!-- example 2 -->
<div class="event-presentation-featured">
  <div class="event-presentation-featued__image-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="event-presentation-featued__image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__content">
    <p>Something smaller</p>
    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__actions">
    <button>Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/><!-- example 3 -->
<div class="event-presentation-featured">
  <div class="event-presentation-featued__image-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="event-presentation-featued__image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__content">
    tiny
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__actions">
    <button>Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define a height for the image (other than a percentage of its container.) It's not too hard to add up the height of the text and margins.

```css
.event-presentation-featured {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 457px;
}

.event-presentation-featued__image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7.2em;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-presentation-featured">
  <div class="event-presentation-featued__image-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="event-presentation-featued__image" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/my57K.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__content">
    <p>August 3, 2022</p>
    <h1>2023 Quad Annual Report</h1>
    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-presentation-featured__actions">
    <button>Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
```